# PN-RT packet malformed

Tags: python, python-3.x, wireshark, ethernet

I tried with that codes to comunicate with Ethernet/Profinet protocol.I found that type of codes. But when I run to the program with that line-1
And i did not get any error. My program running but when i watching the wireshark side my connection information said-2

1

```
sudo python3 discovery.py
```

2

```
Wireshark malformed packet PN-RT
```

Yes it know that is Profinet protocol, but why is the malformed ? How can i fix ?

That is my python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import binascii
from socket import *
from fcntl import ioctl

import struct
import fcntl, struct

value='!6s6sH'


s=socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)

s.bind(('enp2s0',1))

class EtherPacket:
 def __init__(self, dst='25:36:73:32:74:48', src='c3:82:c5:b8:c2:81', protocol=0x8892):
  self.dst = dst                # Destination MAC
  self.src = src                # Source MAC
  self.protocol = protocol      # Protocol Types
  self.raw   =""          # Raw Data
  self.assemble_eth_feilds()



 def assemble_eth_feilds(self):
  # Assemble All Feilds Of Ether Packet

  self.raw = struct.pack( \
      value.encode('ascii'),\
      binascii.unhexlify(self.dst.replace(":","")),\
      binascii.unhexlify(self.src.replace(":","")),\
      self.protocol,\
      )
  return self.raw

def main():
 pkt = EtherPacket()

 s.sendto(pkt.raw, ('enp2s0' , 0 ))


if __name__=='__main__':
   main()
```